# Setting a video file to loop when played on Windows

Tags: video, photos.app, quicktime

We made some videos and downloaded others for a funeral, but the funeral home has Windows.  On the Mac, the only way I know of to make them loop is to play them within QuickTime or Photos.  (Saved/exported files do not loop.)

Already verified that my MacBook can do HDMI through their system, but I have limited confidence in their ability to fully absorb a hasty pre-service tutorial on running four videos in QuickTime.  So I'd prefer to give them the files on USB stick.

Is there a **free or low-cost** way to put a looping setting on `.m4v`, `.mp4`, or `.mov` ?

I know how to make it loop on a DVD, but my laptop apparently has a hardware problem and can't burn a DVD on an external player that is known to work elsewhere.

Comment: AFAIK none of these formats support automated looping.

Comment: Since you didn’t ask this on a windows specific site, I’ll just answer for things that Apple products work well. My hunch is you’d get some good answers from super user if VLC is similarly free and capable of looping on the gear that’s provided.

Comment: I didn't ask there because I don't have access to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You want simple for this.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/vlc-media-player/id650377962

Use any iOS device handy and get VLC video player and have it loop to HDMI. If the funeral home isn’t able to handle your prepared files or [willing to install VLC there](https://superuser.com/questions/977882/prevent-vlc-from-looping-playlist), stick with something you can control easily is my advice.

The playlist feature is easy and you don’t have to hassle with conversion or supporting an app installation on windows at the facility.

You can also use Keynote and iMovie on the iOS device to make and export transition or announcement videos if you get last minute additions or someone shows up with photos you really wish to incorporate in the service at the last moment.

Comment: I do have VLC, but I'm sure they won't install it.  The reason I wanted a looping video is so they don't have to run it on my device.  If they do, both QuickTime and Photos will loop, but neither will export a file that loops.  I don't have time to learn iMovie or Keynote.  Already told the family that the deadline was yesterday.  The funeral is tomorrow.